# An internal error occurred while linting the URL - What is this error?

Tags: facebook-like

I am debugging a website's like button and the trusty linter is returning a troublesome error message:

> An internal error occurred while linting the URL - What is this error?

No other details, just this cryptic error. The linter URL that I am using is: [https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arkclothes.com%2Fmoto-retro-leather-biker-jacket%2F](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.arkclothes.com/moto-retro-leather-biker-jacket/)

Does anybody know what causes this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to open that url in the linter without error. However, if you are still getting the error, please file a bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create.